# Windows Server 2003 SP2 shutdowns suddenly failing/needing hard reset

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, reset, remote-access, shutdown

The last two times I've reset this server, once via remote desktop and once via the Windows Update nag window (also over TS), according to the event log the shutdown has proceeded normally (up to the event logger shutting down), but then it never comes up again.  Going to the console itself we find a black screen with a blinking cursor, and it stays that way overnight, until we finally pull the plug.  Normal startup after that.

What sort of thing could cause this to start happening?  I'm not aware of any major or deep changes to the system (the first time this happened was not on a Windows Update run.)

Comment: Maybe a hw issue? A faulty memory or someghing like that?

Comment: Update firmware/BIOS? Drivers (especially system board related)?

Comment: Is the BIOS programmed to self-destruct after a certain date or something?  I dunno, I'm leary of updating the BIOS without a specific reason.  I guess I should look around for one then and read the changelog...

Comment: What model server?

Comment: HP ProLiant DL380 G4.  @Chris S, the BIOS is up-to-date according to http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?cc=us&prodNameId=3288132&prodSeriesId=397634&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=210

Comment: @Petter H, aren't servers supposed to have all redundant ECC memory and stuff like that?

Comment: ECC isn't "redundant", but most servers require it (the DL380 series all do to my knowledge). Coin-battery on the motherboard dead (does it lose time if you unplug it completely for >10 seconds)?

Comment: My bad.  Not sure, we'll have to test that some time when the server doesn't need to be on.